# Ruby on Rails 5 ActiveJob retry_on, discard_on catch exception order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm using ActiveJob, and I have some questions about the methods discard_on and retry_on that capture exceptions.

1. Does the ActiveJob define their order and execution order? (I guess it's related, but I'm not sure.)
2. Assuming relevant, I hope that retry_on only catches custom exceptions, and that other exceptions are caught by discard_on.

I see discard_on and retry_on in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activejob/lib/active_job/exceptions.rb) is to use rescue_from, because after [rescue_from](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activesupport/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb#L70) defined statement to perform first so here is the way I own assumptions defined, hope you can help me to point out that whether it is right, of course, if you have a better way to achieve the same functionality would you please tell me, thank you very much.

```
class RemoteServiceJob < ActiveJob::Base      
  discard_on StandardError # second catch other exceptions
  retry_on MyCustomException, wait: 5.seconds, attempts: 3 # first catch custom exceptions
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In my tests, the order of execution is exactly the same as I expected, because rescue_from executes in the opposite order of declaration, and the order of exception declaration needs to be the same.

```
def discard_on(exception)
  rescue_from exception do |error|
    if block_given?
      yield self, error
    else
      logger.error "Discarded #{self.class} due to a #{exception}. The original exception was #{error.cause.inspect}."
    end
  end
end

def retry_on(exception, wait: 3.seconds, attempts: 5, queue: nil, priority: nil)
  rescue_from exception do |error|
    if executions < attempts
      logger.error "Retrying #{self.class} in #{wait} seconds, due to a #{exception}. The original exception was #{error.cause.inspect}."
      retry_job wait: determine_delay(wait), queue: queue, priority: priority
    else
      if block_given?
        yield self, error
      else
        logger.error "Stopped retrying #{self.class} due to a #{exception}, which reoccurred on #{executions} attempts. The original exception was #{error.cause.inspect}."
        raise error
      end
    end
  end
end
```